# Query regarding initialization of a vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I was trying the vector implementation in C++ stl and couldn't figure out what exactly does this mean:

**vector< int > vec[N]**

If we simply write int a[10],it's an array of 10 elements. Doesn't the same logic apply to vectors as well?
Isn't it a vector of arrays containing N elements each.Also,when I tried the **.size()** function on **vec** it gave an error" **error: request for member ‘size’ in ‘vec’, which is of non-class type ‘std::vector [3]'"**(Considering N=3)

Please correct me if I misunderstood the concept.

Thanks

Comment: _Isn't it a vector of arrays containing N elements each_ Why would it be? It's array of `N` `vector`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vector is a template class, with array as underlying data structure. Although you don't need to assign size to a vector because it increases its size dynamically, but you may want to reserve space to it while declaring. You can do it by "std::vector< int> vec(size)".
Your syntax actually seems an array of vector of int type, and not a vector of arrays.

Comment: @M.M I actually mentioned the template parameter, but seems like the answer text input escapes the "<" sign. I added a space and it worked :-)

Comment: OK, use backticks ` ` to get in-line code formatting

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will keep that in mind

Comment: The question is unrelated to C++ class templates. Unclear, why a misleading answer like this one received an upvote.

Comment: @IInspectable because the last part of the answer says "Your syntax actually seems an array of vector of int type." :)

Comment: An answer that contains lots of wrong (plus a plagiarized comment that happens to be right) is not useful. If an answer is not useful, it should be downvoted. An upvote is the opposite of a downvote. I'm still puzzled how that happened.